# pandas grouper + time shifting

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Here my pandas:

```
d= {'dates': ['2020-07-16','2020-07-15','2020-07-14','2020-07-13','2020-07-12','2020-07-11','2020-07-10'], 
    'T':[3392,3020,663,2877,366,200,100], 'P': [53,91,0,55,3,22,55]} 
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
df['dates']=pandas.to_datetime(df['dates'])
```

If I pack my pandas each 3 days using Grouper:

```
for _, grp in df.groupby(pandas.Grouper(key='dates', freq='3D')):#
    print (grp)
  dates    T   P
6 2020-07-10  100  55
5 2020-07-11  200  22
4 2020-07-12  366   3
       dates     T   P
3 2020-07-13  2877  55
2 2020-07-14   663   0
1 2020-07-15  3020  91
       dates     T   P
0 2020-07-16  3392  53
```

Now I want to pack each 3 days but with one days shift:

```
8 2020-07-10  100  55
7 2020-07-11  200  22
6 2020-07-12  366   3
       dates     T   P
11 2020-07-11  200  22
10 2020-07-12  366   3
9 2020-07-13  2877  55
       dates     T   P
8 2020-07-12  366   3
7  2020-07-13  2877  55
6  2020-07-14   663   0
         dates     T   P
5 2020-07-13  2877  55
4  2020-07-14   663   0
3 2020-07-15  3020  91
          dates     T   P
2 2020-07-14   663   0
1 2020-07-15  3020  91
0 2020-07-16  3392  53
```

How can I stipulate this to Grouper ?

Comment: what you are looking for is `rolling` operation, but it does not work exactly as the groupby (or at least you can't iterate with a for loop like this). I assume your problem is not to print the dataframe, can you explain what you want to do exactly?

Comment: True :) I would like to sum all the T and P columns each 3 days  with 1 days shifting

Comment: independently? try something like `df.sort_values('dates').rolling('3D', on='dates').sum()`, should give you something close to what you want. if you add the expected output to your question, it will easier to find the exact method :)

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  Only modification is to add ascending to sort_values: df.sort_values('dates',ascending=True).rolling('3d', on='dates').sum() . Thanks